# How do the writing to an HW controller register and DMA work on ARM arch machines?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, arm, dma

while calling this function:

```
static inline void writel(unsigned int v, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    *(volatile unsigned int __force *)addr = cpu_to_le32(v);
}
```

1. Does the address is absoulute or pass through the MMU?
2. DMA - does writing to address is translated by the MMU?
3. Why the registers address in the system aren't mentioned [here](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/memory.txt)?

Comment: Do you call that function from kernel land, e.g. inside a kernel module???

Comment: Yes all the context of this question is in kernel land

Comment: There is an ARM application note titled "Implementing DMA on ARM SMP Systems" @ http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0228a/index.html - which may raise more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answers, hope they help you:

1. Yes, address is translated by the MMU. Address passed to `writel` should be Virtual Address (VA) obtained via `ioremap` call. `ioremap` will take Physical Address (PA).
2. No, address is not translated by the MMU. Address passed to DMA should be Physical Address. A typical DMA is a dedicated peripheral which exists outside of the MMU.
3. You have to search, for example, 'bcm2835 arm peripherals', not 'Kernel Memory Layout on ARM Linux'.  As a hint, if you want to find register location inside linux kernel, do search for `ioremap` inside linux-kernel-tree/arch/arm.

Comment: Is 2. true for newer ARMs like A53 ? They have IOMMU for each axi channel. Does SMMU affect addressing on AXI ports?